# How do I only display the minimum of a count in sparql?

Tags: count, aggregate, sparql, aggregate-functions, min

Let's say I have data about a school and I want to output only the name of the teacher(s) who has the fewest (or joint fewest) male students. So my data might look something like this:

```
job:teacher job:responsibleFor job:Pupil
human:Person human:gender "male" (or "female")
human:Person job:hasOccupation job:Pupil (or Teacher)
```

so at the moment my code outputs a list of teachers by their counts of male pupils and it looks something like this:

```
prefix job
prefix human

SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?student) AS ?count) ?teacher
WHERE{
?student a job:pupil.
?studentHuman job:hasOccupation ?student.
?studentHuman human:gender ?studentGender.
filter(?studentGender = "male")

?teacher job:responsibleFor ?student
}
GROUP BY ?teacher
```

This will print out the teachers along with their respective number of male pupils. I know I can order the output and limit it but I don't know how many classes might all have the same minimum number of male pupils. I want to print out only the teacher(s) with the minimum (or joint minimum) number of male pupils. I've tried using `MIN` but it doesn't work with `COUNT`. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: You can use a sub-SELECT to get the minimum count value and then return only those teacher whose count equals the minimum.

Comment: That seems to work to print out the minimum value (so in this case the minimum number of male students in any class) but when I try and print out the name of the teacher doesn't give any name unless I include the name in the inner SELECT in which case the outer SELECT is ignored completely...

Comment: If you can ORDER BY some value, then you can LIMIT the query results to 1, in which you can the result with the largest or smallest value.  E.g,. `select ?p (count(?q) as ?qs) { ... } order by ?qs limit 1`.  Of course, that explicitly restricts you to one result;  that doesn't help if you have multiple such results.

Comment: Nobody can help fix your sub-SELECT attempt, if you don't show that query... The engine (name and version) you're running this on can also matter.